# HTML Validation anchor tag

Tags: html, css, validation, html-lists, anchor

I'm having a simple problem with validating a piece of code. would like some input as to what i'm doing wrong. when i validate it it gives a warning saying i should close the anchor tag. but i need both the header and the paragraph to be highlighted using css. the html code is below

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <div class="menu-dropdown">
        <div class="menu-items">
            <a href="#">
            <h4>Why Choose Cyberskills?</h4>
            <p>There are a number of reason to choose Cyberskills. Click here to find out more...</p>
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

the css code is below

```
menu-items a{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
.menu-items a:hover{
display: block;
background: #666666;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;  
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In HTML5 this is valid. In XHTML 1.0 Transitional not, cause it is not allowed to put "block tags" inside of a link. Block tags are tags in HTML which got `display: block` per default, like: `div`, `p`, `h1`, `h2`, ...

You could use `<span>` instead of `h4` and `p` **or** put the links inside of `h4` and `p`.

Comment: I'm interested in hearing what the community thinks of this. Both solutions, while creating valid HTML, are ugly. How about just using one `a` in the `h4`, dispensing with the `p` and putting the text in a title on the `a`?

Comment: What you have suggested produces a totally different output. -- Okay, using `span` would remove the sematic part, which is not the recommended solution - but writing a link in each item isn't ugly! It is necessary, if you want to stay valid!

Comment: @Mr Lister, all alternatives result in longish link texts, which are not good for usability, accessibility, and search engines. Perhaps the best approach is to make just the last part of the `p` text a link, reformulating it, e.g.: Read the full story: `<a href=...>Reasons for Choosing Cyberskill</a>`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I meant, my solution would have been to use the current `h4` content as the link text, and to use the current `p` content as a title attribute in the `a`.

Comment: @Armin Adding an `a` to both the `h4` and the `p` is ugly in the structural sense, because it adds markup that shouldn't be necessary in the first place. (I think it's also ugly to look at on the screen, but that's just personal opinion.) You're right of course that the original HTML5 source also has this.

Comment: Yes, but it is! So you have no choice, except making it "ugly", using HTML5 or loosing validity.